# Python code showing Error in Jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

The following is the python code that was showing correct output in command line but showing error in Jupyter. I installed python distribution called Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit) containing Python 2.7.11 .

The following code takes a nested list and prints the flattened list.

```
def printWholeList(list1):

    for iterator in list1 :
        if(isinstance(iterator,list)):
                printWholeList(iterator)
        else:
            print(iterator)

list1 = ['a' ,'b' ,['c','d',['p','h']]]
printWholeList(list1)
```

**Output in command line :**

> C:\Users\KarmicSmoke>python
>   C:\Users\KarmicSmoke\Downloads\FirstProg.py
>    a
>   b
>   c
>  
>   d
>   p
>   h

**Output in Jupyter :**

-

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-3df571b6bccc> in <module>()
      8 
      9 list1 = ['a' ,'b' ,['c','d',['p','h']]]
---> 10 printWholeList(list1)
     11 
     12 

<ipython-input-64-3df571b6bccc> in printWholeList(list1)
      2 
      3     for iterator in list1 :
----> 4         if(isinstance(iterator,list)):
      5                 printWholeList(iterator)
      6         else:

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

Why do this error occurs ?

Update :
Earlier I declared 'list' as local variable name and that error came . Then , I changed it to 'list1' as you can see above. This all I did in Jupyter notebook. Now  I closed it , opened it again and VOILA it shows correct output . What should i infer from this behaviour of Jupyter ? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
def printWholeList(list1):

    for it in list1 :
        if(isinstance(it,__builtins__.list)):
                printWholeList(it)
        else:
            print(it)

list1 = ['a' ,'b' ,['c','d',['p','h']]]
printWholeList(list1)
```

You have probably defined a var named list in your notebook.
Don't use reserved keywords for that !

Comment: Earlier I declared 'list' as local variable name and that error came . Then , I changed it to 'list1' as you can see above. This all I did in Jupyter notebook.  Now upon reading your answer , I closed it , opened it again and VOILA it shows correct output . What should i infer from this behaviour of Jupyter ?

Comment: A notebook keeps in memory all vars you have delcared that's why you had the issue and when you reopened the notebook, the list var had disapeared but beware of your naming of vars ( or use __builtins__.list to avoid any confusion)